# Is it possible to return div element in React Custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-custom-hooks

I have an array of objects inside custom hook. I want to return JSX inside one of these objects, but I get `Cannot find name 'div'.ts(2304)` error. Is there any solution for this problem?

```
const columns: IColumn[] = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        key: 'column2',
        onRender: (item: IDocumentItem) => {
          return <div style={{ fontWeight: 'normal' }}>{item.type}</div>; 
        },
        data: 'string',
      },
...

    ],
    [setFieldName, setIndex, setItemSort]
  );
```

Comment: You can use `React.createElement` in `onRender` method.

Comment: What error do you see? Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support).

Comment: @MithatErcan Thanks, but it's not something that I look for. I also have another <div> which includes some lines of codes and it seems it's pretty challenging to implement.